# Determine if a Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equation can be converted to a Linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an *apriori* criterion to determine if a nonlinear ordinary differential equation can be transformed into a linear ODE?  For example, the Bernoulli equation,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x)y^n, n \neq 0, 1$$
on the surface, appears to be nonlinear.  For example, I don't even know how to write a linearity test for this equation in terms of a linear differential operator $L$,
$$L[\alpha y + \beta x] = \alpha L[y] + \beta L[x].$$

However, the substitution, $v = y^{1-n}$ will transform this nonlinear ODE into a linear one.